# Firebase - Changing my project's Country/region

Tags: firebase

I've mistakenly chosen the wrong Country/region during the creation of a project in firebase.
As you can see here:

[image: Create a project]

Can this be fixed?
(I know the project Id cannot be changed and I like the Id I've chosen...)

Comment: What exactly is being impacted by an incorrect location here?

Comment: "This represents the country/region of your organisation/company. Your selection also sets the appropriate currency for your revenue reporting. The selected country does not determine the location of your data for Firebase features. Google may process and store Customer Data anywhere Google or its agents maintain facilities."

Comment: There is no way to change that

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs say](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/locations), in bold no less:

> **Once you select a location for your project, you cannot change it.**

You can however change the location for certain services (e.g. Cloud Functions and Cloud Storage) when setting them up.